# How can I update a single field in psql with the contents of a file?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am trying to do the following:

```
UPDATE bodycontent set body=CONTENT_FROM_FILE where contentid=12943363;
```

I tried the following based on the highest voted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968039/postgresql-inserting-value-of-a-column-from-a-file).

```
\set contentfill `cat Foo.txt`
UPDATE bodycontent set body=:'contentfill' where contentid=12943363;
```

This results in the following error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"                                                  
LINE 1: UPDATE bodycontent set body=:'contentfill' where contentid=1...
```

Is there a clean, simple and effective way to achieve this on the `psql` command line?

Here is the output of `psql --version`:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.17
```

Comment: @MilenA.Radev, Updated with version.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I discovered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588796/391161), which does not directly discuss the problem of reading files, but gave me the necessary ingredient to make this work for my ancient `Postgres`.

```
\set contentFill `cat Foo.txt`
\set quoted_contentFill '\'' :contentFill '\''
UPDATE bodycontent SET body=:quoted_contentFill WHERE contentid=12943363;
```

Naturally, this will fail if there are un-escaped quotes inside `Foo.txt`, but I can easily preprocess to ensure there are none.